# cURL error 60 when calling Azure Table Storage from App Service running PHP

Tags: php, azure, ssl, curl

I am using this SDK:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php

And this addon:
https://github.com/cocteau666/php-azure-session

To handle session in Azure Table Storage for my PHP based Wordpress site running in an Azure App Service.

When running the code from the last link, I get the following error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I am not using cURL directly, I am just using it through the code in **azure-sdk-for-php** and I cannot change that code.

So how do I identify which certificate is the problem and then **globally** define it so it will work.

I have already tried running this code just before and it doesn't throw an exception but it doesn't make any difference either. I don't know if I am using the correct .pem or whether this affects cURL globally.

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/issues/70):

(although I used FTP for most of these steps)

1. Open the web app in portal.azure.com
2. Go to Application Settings and add this value in the App settings section: PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR = d:\home\site\ini
3. Open web app's scm panel, for example - https://osi-bout-test.scm.azurewebsites.net/
4. Go to Debug Console > CMD
5. Open the "site" folder
6. Upload the "cacert.pem" file (download it from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
7. Create/open the "ini" folder
8. Create/open file with the name "settings.ini"
9. Put this line inside the file: curl.cainfo = "D:\home\site\cacert.pem"
10. Go back to the app in the portal.azure.com and STOP and then START.

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark it as an answer so that other folks can benefit from it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have marked it as an answer now. I wanted to do it immediately, but I am not allowed to answer my own question and mark it as answer without a grace period.